# Adding a Guest user to a Team using Graph API throws Request_ResourceNotFound error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We implemented Guest user provision through invitation process [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-beta) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

As soon as the invitation is redeemed we add the Guest user to a Team using add member API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

We followed the documented invitation process and everything worked as expected. But recently we saw the following error when our application tries to add the Guest user to a team using add member API

```
     "error": {
       "error": {
         "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
         "message": "Resource '495a2b25-00ad-4d34-af84-0118b68c97cc' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
         "innerError": {
           "date": "2021-08-02T22:29:13",
           "request-id": "80706a76-2404-4d39-a800-cbddd12a7402",
           "client-request-id": "80706a76-2404-4d39-a800-cbddd12a7402"
         }
       }
     },
     "error_status": 404
   }
```

It seems that the guest user id `495a2b25-00ad-4d34-af84-0118b68c97cc` is not available in our tenant. Azure portal shows status as invitation accepted(Later the User deleted his guest account).

1. We would like to know what exactly causes this error and best practices to avoid it.
2. Is there any latency on adding the user as a Guest user to a Tenant ? This document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-beta) says once the invitation redemption is completed the invited user becomes an external user in the organization.
3. Is there a way \ API available to check\confirm the Guest user is added and available for using with add member API ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the add member API call happen after the user has deleted their account? In this case the 404 is expected. If not then you are performing add member when the user creation and sync is not completed. Let me look around for docs on the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried to repro this at our end and it is working fine for us.

1. 404 error occurs if the resource is not found and in this case If the add member API is called after the user has deleted his guest account then 404 is expected.
2. There is no latency in adding the user as a Guest user to a Tenant.
3. Please refer this [Invitation status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/customize-invitation-api#invitation-status) to see if the user has accepted it.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT . The provided [Invitation status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/customize-invitation-api#invitation-status) shows the use of Power Shell to get the status but we need to get it using Graph API. 
We found that if we use [Get User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with $select=externalUserState  it will return the state of the User . It says 'external User' Will it work for guest user too ?

Comment: Thanks Meghana-MSFT for the confirmation